Add Where clause based on parameter
I want to add a where clause if a boolean parameter is true or not.
So for example
If @IncludeAllProducts = 0 then select only those that have a name of 'Drink', otherwise don't add the where clause at all.
If @IncludeAllProducts=1 then I want this:
Select * 
from Products
Order By Name

However if @IncludeAllProducts=0 then I want this:
Select * from Products
WHERE Name='Drink'
Order By Name

The actual query is very large so I do not want to have two slightly different versions for each condition, I would like to dynamically add a where depending on the parameter.

Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL - enjoy!

You can have a case statement on your where clause, something like this:
WHERE 1 = CASE
WHEN @ IncludeAllProducts = 1 THEN 1
WHEn @ IncludeAllProducts = 0 AND Name='Drink' THEN 1
ELSE 0
END

Simple AND/OR logic is all you need here

WHERE Name='Drink' OR @IncludeAllProducts = 1

You can leverage an optional parameter in the query.
DECLARE @ProductType AS NVARCHAR(32) = NULL

-- Assume you only want drinks.
-- Try it for "Food" or whatever is in your data.
-- Comment this out to keep @ProductType NULL and it'll return all Products.
SET @ProductType = 'Drink'

SELECT
    p.*
FROM
    Products p
WHERE
    (p.ProductType = @ProductType OR @ProductType IS NULL)

